# How to remove gsoap version from http header

Tags: header, http-headers, gsoap

```
POST / engelen/calcserver.cgi HTTP/1.1 
Host: websrv.cs.fsu.edu 
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 464 
Connection: close 
SOAPAction: ""
```

How can I remove the User-agent header ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm... not sure why you want to do that, since user agent identification does not change in any way how services are provided. You could change the `stdsoap2.cpp` source code for `http_post()` to remove this code that produces this header. Or perhaps write your own `http_post()` callback to produce HTTP headers?